# Is Microsoft's fopen commit mode flag broken on Windows 7?

Tags: c, windows-7, file-io, commit, fopen

I write the engine for our company's products, which are designed to run on our clients kiosks.  This includes code to commit file writes to disk.

We have no control over the client's choice of hardware or OS, and for the first time we've been given Windows 7 Embedded to work with.  Suddenly, our secure writes have started failing if power is lost immediately after the flush.

Although including commode.obj causes fflush to commit, even on Win7, I've always preferred to use the MS-specific commit mode flag ("c") on Windows (the Linux version uses a completely different method), because as I write the library not the products, I can never be sure that commode.obj has actually been included, so I can't throw an error.

```
FILE* p_f = fopen("foo.dat", "wbc");
fwrite(p_important_stuff, 1, size, p_f);
fflush(p_f);
```

So my question is: Is the commit mode flag broken on Win7, and if so is there a way I can *guarantee* commode.obj is included, or is there some other way I can change the state of the global commit flag?

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely other issues than those exposed by the C file interfaces. I'm thinking about OS and filesystem decisions to delay writes, and HDD caching, which may explain the behavior you see.

ASide from that, you should be able to always include the `commode.obj` simply by linking your library as a DLL instead of a static library.

Comment: As far as I know, the commit mode flag is supposed to change the file local version of the global flag that commode.obj does, and commode.obj works while "c" doesn't.  The client informs me that they've disabled file caching for the drive (a 2.5" laptop one), at least as much as they can.  Good point about using DLLs though, although it makes releasing source code to Government test houses harder.

Comment: How does a DLL make releasing source code harder? If they run into trouble because they didn't build your library correctly, isn't that *their* problem? (I know, being naive...)

Comment: Unfortunately it is our problem.  If they can't compile stuff they just fail us outright, and another submission costs us thousands.  And they're not that expert, I had to explain to one of them how the FPU control word affected floating point casts.  All they do is check the checksum of the compiled code against the one we release.

Answer (score 0):

We also had issues with the inclusion of commode.obj not working for us.

Rather than using `fflush(...)`, we used `_flushall()` with no parameters.

More info in his archived KB article https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66052/